# Necessity and Sufficiency

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm learning to write mathematical proofs. When the statement to be proven is in the form "$p$ if and only if $q$", the proof is often broken into two parts: necessity and sufficiency. I wonder whether I should organize my proof like:

Necessity: $p \Rightarrow q$

Sufficiency: $ q \Rightarrow p$

... or vice versa?

Since $p \Leftrightarrow q$ is is equivalent to $q \Leftrightarrow p$, does it really matter? Is there any accepted practise to put $p \Rightarrow q$ in necessity or sufficiency, depending on the order in which the statements are presented?

Comment: Regarding the question I think you asked, it does matter. $p\to q$ means $p$ is sufficient for $q$. $q\to p$ means $p$ is necessary for $q$. That's just the English meanings of the words. As to the question I think @Rasmus answered, whether it matters which order you prove $p\to q$ and $q\to p$ in, no, that makes no difference.

Comment: As to why it should matter, if you're in a situation where $q\to p$ is true but $p\leftrightarrow q$ isn't, you might-though it's not all that common-see someone writing sentences like "$p$ is necessary for $q$ to hold" instead of "$q$ implies $p$" or "$p$ holds only if $q$ does".

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I was really asking was when p<=>q, which condition do we call necessary and which sufficient, since each of them is both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there is no difference, but it is common to put the "subject" first. An example will make more sense.

---

A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the usual topology) is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

vs.

A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the usual topology) is closed and bounded if and only if it is compact.

---

They are both the same statement, but the *purpose* of the theorem is to characterize compactness, not to characterize (closed and bounded)-ness. For this reason, it is more pleasing (I think) to mention compactness first and also to use phrases like "necessary for compactness" and "sufficient for compactness".