# Necessary and sufficient condition vs iff.

Tags: logic

I have seen various theorems, where in statement "if and only if" is written and in the proof they call one statement as necessary and other as sufficient. I often get confused regarding the relationship of "if" and "only if" with "necessity" and "sufficiency or converse". My question is, "A holds if and only if B holds".In this statement which part is necessary and which is converse between the following two:
1)suppose A holds, then B follows.
2)Suppose B holds, then A follows.

Comment: Do [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216210/necessity-and-sufficiency?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018188/using-terms-necessary-and-sufficient-when-writing-proofs-for-logical-equival?rq=1) help clarify your thoughts?

Comment: Suppose that P being true implies that Q is true, i.e., $P\implies Q.$

This means precisely that there is no way for P to be true and Q false.

In other words: P is true *only if* Q is true.

Similarly, $P\rightarrow Q$ is read as $“P$ only if $Q.”$